# How to wait Angular reactive form until text complete?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am using angular reactive form in my application. And when user type URL in text box, I am sending ajax request to server.

```
 this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
      if (this.myForm.valid) {
        // call ajax for this.myForm.value.url
      }
 }
```

But when I type the letters in order `"h", "ht", "http",` the request is sending immediately. I want to send request after I complete the type. So I think need a pipe for wait, but which?

Comment: I suggest `debounceTime`.

Comment: In such logic it's better to have a button to send the request.

Comment: If you know exactly, how the URL should look like, you can use a pattern to validate. Actually, it's not about rxjs..

Comment: https://link.medium.com/NNRCFsxXN3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `debounceTime` rxjs operator (with a millisecond parameter):

```
import {debounceTime} from "rxjs/operators";

this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
debounceTime(1000)
).subscribe(...)
```

If you want to go further and avoid doing 2 subscriptions (for the form and the api call), you can use `switchMap` rxjs operator :

```
import {debounceTime, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";

this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  switchMap(value => {
    if (this.form.valid) {
    return this.api.save(value.url)
    }
  })
).subscribe(// return the result of the api call)
```

Comment: I would also add distinctUntilChanged: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged. It only emits if the new value is different from the last. regards

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need with the condition :

Example:

```
import {debounceTime} from "rxjs/operators";

this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  this.myForm.valid,
  debounceTime(1000))
).subscribe(res => this.data = res);
```